# How to filter out values from a nested objects in javascript

Tags: javascript, recursion, ecmascript-6, lodash

I need to access properties of a JavaScript object array and convert it to a new array. The array takes a form like this.

```
Company = [
    { 
      name:"A", 
      items:[
          { name:"AA",
            items:[
             { name:"AAA",
               items:[...]
             },
             { name:"AAB",
               items:[...]
             }
          ]
       },
        { name:"AB",items:[{},{}]}
       ]
    },
    {
      name:"B", items:[{ name:"BA",items:[{...},{...}]},{ name:"BB",items:[{...},{...}]}]
    },
    {
      name:"C", items:[{ name:"CA",items:[{...},{...}]},{ name:"CB",items:[{...},{...}]}]
    }
........
];
```

I need to convert this to a structure like this.

```
Company = [
    { title: 'A',
      children: [
         { title: 'AA',
            children: [{ title: 'AAA',children: [..] }] 
         },
         { title: 'AB', children: [{ title: 'ABA',children: [..] }
       ]
    },
    { title: 'B',
      children: [
         { title: 'BA',
            children: [{ title: 'BAA',children: [..] }] 
         },
         { title: 'BB', children: [{ title: 'BBA',children: [..] }
       ]
    },
  .........
   ]
```

I tried to use ES6 Map,Reducer,Filter and lodash to get the array converted but i couldn't. Any idea on how to achive this?. Here is what i have tried out so far

```
function checkitems(data){
  if (typeof data.items !== "undefined" || data.items.length > 0) {

    data.items.map(dept => {
      return {
        title: dept.name,
        children: checkitems(dept)
      };
    });
  }
  return;
    }

    company.map((dept)=>{
       return {
         title:dept.name,
         children: checkitems(dept)
       }
    });
```

Comment: Please provide the code using Map reduce and filter and what you have tried.

Comment: you will need recursion to solve this as long as there can be "n" layers of `children`

Comment: @DTul  I have updated my question

Comment: @messerbill i have updated my question with what i have done using recursion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could recursively update the `items` like this:

```js
const Company=[{name:"A",items:[{name:"AA",items:[{name:"AAA",},{name:"AAB",}]},{name:"AB"}]},{name:"B",items:[{name:"BA",items:[{name:"BAA",},{name:"BAB",}]},{name:"BB",}]},{name:"C",items:[{name:"CA",},{name:"CB",}]}];

function trasnform(array) {
  return array.map(({ name , items }) => {
    const obj = { title: name }
    if(items)
      obj.children = trasnform(items);
      
    return obj;
  })
}

console.log(trasnform(Company))
```

Answer (score 1):

Using destructuring assignment and default arguments -

```
const transform = (arr = []) =>
  arr.map(({ name, items = [] }) =>
    ({ title: name, children: transform(items) })
  )
```

Decomposed using mutual recursion -

```
const transform1 = ({ name, items = [] }) =>
  ({ title: name, children: transform(items) })

const transform = (arr = []) =>
  arr.map(transform1)
```